# Increasing tomcat keep-alive timeout

Tags: tomcat, timeout, sap-commerce-cloud, keep-alive

I'm trying to increase the timeout on my tomcat server. My current server.xml onfiguration is :

```
<Connector port="9002"
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxPostSize="4194304"
maxThreads="150"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
executor="hybrisExecutor"
enableLookups="false"
acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="120000"               
keepAliveTimeout="600"
disableUploadTimeout="true"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="false"
sslProtocol = "TLS"
keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/lib/keystore"
keystorePass=""/>
```

However when the request is made. It seems that the keep-alive timeout is changed to 5 for some reason. Is there anything wrong with my approach?

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 16:12:27 GMT
Expires: 0
**Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=81**
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=38E87AAAED514858A91383908307CBF1; Path=""; 
Secure;HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0):

There are server.xml files in multiple directories. There are 2 directories. One with configurable templates (/hybris/config/tomcat/conf), that are enriched with configuration parameters and then put to the tomcat directory (/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/conf) for use during the ant all or ant server process.

If you make changes to the version in the platform directory, they will be overwritten during ant all or ant server. Make sure to change the server.xml in the config directory.